# How to build a Play2 project using play-yeoman from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, yeoman

Now I am reading a code of following project. I am a newbie of Play2(w/ Scala).

https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed#master

When I built it with instruction written in above link, it worked fine.(It was on a terminal).
But when I opened that project with IntelliJ IDEA, I got following error.

```
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
'force' not enabled
Will run: [grunt, --gruntfile=Gruntfile.js, watch] in /Users/chabashilah/
/prv/dev/test/test-play-silhouette-angular-seed/ui
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "/Users/chabashilah/
/prv/dev/test/test-play-silhouette-angular-seed/ui"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last compile:run' for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "/Users/chabashilah/
/prv/dev/test/test-play-silhouette-angular-seed/ui"): error=2, No such file or directory
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 2015/03/28 0:36:40
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

I guess this is a small configuration mistake but couldn't find why it happens.
How can I make it build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about this area, but the obvious solution (in my ignorance) would be to add the directory where grunt is located to your path, and then restart Intellij to ensure that the path change is picked up.  Have you tried that?